# Entity Framework save class without an Id from external source

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Given a class from an external source (in my case a NuGet Package):

```
public class Apple {
    // Some properties
}
```

What is the best method to store this in a `dbContext`?

Note that I cannot use the following since Apple does not have an Id:

```
DbSet<Apple> Apples {get; set;}
```

Right now my (naive) solution is to have mapper functions to store a similar class in the database I that have created, and then call these when I want to access an object from the NuGet Package.

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to solve that problem, there are 2 solutions i can offer: (you need to add proper reference of the original Apple class)

### First solution (With Inheritance - simpler one)

I would create a class inherited from Apple class and an Id property to it.

```
public class MyApple: Apple
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then add the newly created class to DbContext.

```
DbSet<MyApple> MyApples {get; set;}
```

### Second solution (With ComplexType)

Second solution would be creating a class like the above one, without inheritance and referencing to Apple class.

```
public class MyApple
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Apple Apple { get; set; }
}
```

And making the original Apple class as ComplexType

#### a) via Fluent Api (in your context class)

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.ComplexType<Apple>();
}
```

In the second solution, you will see the column names like; Apple_OriginalColumnName1, Apple_OriginalColumnName2

To fix those you may change those with HasColumnName in Fluent Api.

#### b) or via Data Annotation

(if you can modify Apple class, but you don't want to add Id property here. Not proper for your question but it may be simpler for others..)

```
[ComplexType]
public class Apple
{
     [Column("ColumnName1")]
     public string ColumnName1 { get; set; }
     ...
}
```

`[ComplexType] attributeof` the table is the core solution here.

`[Column("ColumnName1")]` attribute will fix the `Apple_ColumnName1` problem.

Comment: I am unable to modify the 'Apple' class, so your first solution is exactly what I wanted to achieve. Thank you for the quality response.

Comment: If you cannot modify it then first or second (a) would be ok for you. Your welcome.